# (Joomla 3.2.x) Form in article

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How to add form with method="post" into article (or module) to work properly?
I just added form (script for form calculation is already added to template) in article via "tools -> html", and it's not working.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: No reaction after pushing button. (Form properly working in clear html)

Answer (score 1):

Is it neccessary to write the form yourself?

Using an extension like **rsforms** or a free one like **chronoforms** is a good idea.

http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms.html
http://www.rsjoomla.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=L2Rvd25sb2Fkcy5odG1s

Comment: I've used RSForms and the Pro version with good results. That said, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: While you are right, Unless you're developing a component/module, you may as well use extensions like those